# How can I achieve a look and feel similar to the Facebook app's welcome screen?

Tags: android, user-interface, splash-screen, android-transitions

I use a splash screen as welcome screen in my app, but after loading the splash screen, it glitches or starts jumping before loading the main XML layout instead of loading smoothly.

I really like the look and feel of the Facebook app's welcome screen, which displays the Facebook logo then smoothly slides upwards to reveal the login screen.

How can I go about replicating this look and feel?

Comment: be more clear, is your app crashes?

Comment: please enter more details. what do you mean by "glitches" ? does it crash? is it displayed the wrong way? what does your code look like now? I assume you are using just 1 activity (or maybe 2 for the splash screen) please post the relevant code.

Comment: i update my question and try to explain more,thanks

Comment: I believe you are looking for transitions while moving between activities